# Inconsistent rounding of "months ago"

Tags: bug, status-deferred, rounding

Today I saw [a question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9073/17) that was deleted by the "1 year without activity" roomba. Curiously, it said "asked 1 year, 3 months ago" and "deleted 4 months ago". Was it deleted too early, I wondered? No: turns out it was deleted *more* than 1 year after being asked. The "asked ... ago" time is being rounded ***down*** and the "deleted ... ago" is being rounded ***up***.

[image: screenshot (click for full size version)]

Why is the rounding inconsistent here? Tagged [very-minor-pedantic-bug](/questions/tagged/very-minor-pedantic-bug) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), we don't have immediate plans to work on this request. We'll revisit it at a later date and provide more details here when it has been prioritized and/or completed.

Comment: Fair enough :-) I did say very minor pedantic bug.

Answer (score 3):

This bug can also lead to (apparent) time travel, resulting in questions being (apparently) closed and deleted before they were asked:

[image: Question asked 2 months ago, closed and deleted 3 months ago]

The [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406972/208273) was asked 2021-04-20 23:43:19Z, closed 2021-04-22 06:29:22Z, and deleted 2021-04-22 17:47:42Z.  However, it's described as asked 2 months ago, closed 3 months ago, and deleted 3 months ago.

Still a minor pedantic bug, but made me do a double-take here.

Comment: Are you using a userscript or something for the dark mode on meta? I've tested a couple of ones before but didn't like them. The one you're using looks somewhat like the dark mode on main.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes, it's [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/).  Works basically everywhere.  I'd highly recommend it.