# Inconsistent date in close description

Tags: bug, closed-questions, timestamps

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344532) post is related but since I wasn't able to [communicate with staff through comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1234291), I am posting a new post. Please do not close it as duplicate.

My post is also not a duplicate of [Inconsistent rounding of "months ago"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347355) as it is about a deleted question whereas in my case it is a closed question.

---

I am talking about this question: [Software Updater is saying "You stopped the check for updates". What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1276498)

[image: Screenshot of part of https://askubuntu.com/q/1276498]

The question was *asked* **11 months ago** and the question was *closed* **12 months ago**.
(Now the question has become a bit old and the inconsistent dates are gone, but I feel the issue still exits).

A question cannot be closed even before it existed.

This is a bug and needs to be fixed.

Also posted here: [Inconsistent date in close description](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19738)

Comment: [Also mentioned on CGCC Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23877/bugged-question-possibly-rounding-issue)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistent rounding of "months ago"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347355/inconsistent-rounding-of-months-ago)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks for the link. But it should not be [tag:status-bydesign] IMO.

Comment: @RandomPerson Yeah, I'm updating my answer to that, having seen JNat's response/retagging of the duplicate question

Comment: @RafaelTavares That question is about a deleted question whereas my question is about a closed question.

Comment: It is the same problem, it'll have the same answer and potentially be fixed in the same date. We don't need one post for each situation it occurs, if they are basically the same (question deleted, closed, locked, answer deleted etc.). Also, did you see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367530/818993)? It's about a closed question.